# ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/transaction/SystemException

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, jboss-arquillian, weblogic12c

I'm trying to use Arquillian against weblogic 12C.

I put the following configuration in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.CR7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.CR7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
        <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-beta-5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-wls-remote-12.1</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Alpha2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>weblogic</groupId>
        <artifactId>wlfullclient</artifactId>
        <version>12.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0.Final</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Then, I configured the arquillian.xml file as following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<arquillian xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://jboss.org.schema/arquillian"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">
    <container qualifier="weblogic" default="true">
        <configuration>
            <protocol type="Servlet 3.0">
                <property name="executionType">REMOTE</property>
            </protocol>
            <property name="adminUrl">t3://localhost:7001</property>
            <property name="adminUserName">weblogic</property>
            <property name="adminPassword">weblogic1</property>
            <property name="target">AdminServer</property>
            <property name="wlsHome">c:\java\servers\wls12c\wlserver</property>
        </configuration>
    </container>
</arquillian>
```

Finally I tried to "create" an archive with Arquillian :

```
 JavaArchive ejbArchive = ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class,"jee6app-ejb.jar").addAsResource("META-INF/persistence.xml","META-INF/persistence.xml").addPackages(false,Adr.class.getPackage(),Service.class.getPackage());
           EnterpriseArchive earArchive = ShrinkWrap.create(EnterpriseArchive.class, "jee6app.ear").addAsModule(ejbArchive).addAsLibraries(
                   new File("target/test-libs/validation-api.jar"),
                   new File("target/test-libs/hibernate-entitymanager.jar"),
                   new File("target/test-libs/hibernate-validator.jar"),
                   new File("target/test-libs/javassist.jar"),
                   new File("target/test-libs/asm.jar"),
                   new File("target/test-libs/cglib.jar"),
                   new File("target/test-libs/hibernate-jpa.jar"),
                   new File("target/test-libs/hibernate-commons-annotations.jar"),
                   new File("target/test-libs/hibernate-annotations.jar"),
                   new File("target/test-libs/slf4j-api.jar"),
                   new File("target/test-libs/jta.jar"),
                   new File("target/test-libs/dom4j.jar"),
                   new File("target/test-libs/commons-collections.jar"),
                   new File("target/test-libs/antlr.jar"),
                   new File("target/test-libs/hibernate-core.jar")
                   );

            return earArchive;
```

So, after all of those things, I always have the following error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/transaction/SystemException
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
```

What's wrong in my configuration? As you can see before, I tried to add to the classpath the wlfullclient jar and jboss api jar

Thanks in advance for your help

Regards

Comment: Did you try using Arquillian Core 1.0.3.Final or 1.0.1.Final? CR7 is very old.

Comment: I've been trying those releases and I have the same behaviour

Comment: Can you see if you're pulling in the Oracle published `javaee-api` artifact by any chance? `mvn dependency:tree` would help here. You'll need to specify the Maven profiles, if you're using ones that need activation.

Comment: Yes indeed I use the javaee6-api artifact. After spotting all around the web, I saw that this artifact is ok for builds but unusable for runtime such as arquillian tests or simple junit tests.

Comment: Yes, you'll need to exclude that artifact for your tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing that you're pulling in the `javaee-api` artifact into your test scope, you might want to use the JBoss provided APIs,

See [this Arquillian FAQ](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/WhatsTheCauseOfThisExceptionJavalangClassFormatErrorAbsentCode) for more details.

Or, in the case of WLS, you could rely on the `wlfullclient.jar` to provide the required classes. You'll need to install it into a Maven repo (perhaps into an organization-wide one), and then reference it in your project.

Answer (score 10):

I had similar error with JBoss 7.1 and 6.1 eap with remote EJB call, on class file
javax/ejb/EJBException

And resolved the problem switching from

```
<groupId>javax</groupId> 
<artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId> 
<version>6.0</version>
```

to

```
<groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
<artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
<version>6.0-5</version>
```

Maybe this should help ?
BR

Comment: Awesome. Note: 6.0-5 is out.